# Pushing Object to array does not reflect at ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am updating an array by pushing the Json object returned by MVC controller to an array in Angular JS controller.

Following is the code `sports-controller.js`

```
portsApp.controller("SportsController", ["$scope","$http",function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.data = { id: "rehmat" };
    $scope.sports = [];
    $scope.selectedSport ={};
    $scope.sportsObj = {};

    $scope.SportsModel = {};

    $scope.sport = {};

    $scope.remoteUrlRequestFn = function (str) {
        return { term: str };
    };

    function genericSuccess(res) {
        return res.data; // yes, really.
    }
    $scope.selectedSport = function (selected) {        
        $scope.sport =
            {
            title: selected.originalObject.name,
            parent_id: selected.originalObject.parent,
            sports_id: selected.originalObject.sports_id,
            user_id: selected.originalObject.uid

        }       
        $http.post("/usersports/post_sport", $scope.sport).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {           
            $scope.sports.push(genericSuccess(data).sport);
            console.log($scope.sports);
        });

    }

    $scope.UpdateSport = function (id) {
        if(id > 0)
        {
            $http.post("/usersports/update_sports", { user_sport_id: id }).then(function (data,status,headers,config){

                if(data.Success)
                {
                   alert(data.Message)
                }else
                {
                    alert(data.Message)
                }

            })
        }
    }


}
])
```

**VIEW :**

```
<div class="container sports-c" ng-app="SportsApp" >
    <!--ADD SPORTS TEXT-->
    <div class="col-lg-12" ng-controller="SportsController">
        {{sports}}
        <div class="add-sports-text  ">

            <h1 style="text-align:center;" class="animated jello">ADD SPORTS</h1>
            <hr style="width:30%">
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;">
            <label for="search" style="text-align:center;"> SEARCH</label>
            <angucomplete-alt id="sports_input_box"
                              placeholder="Search Sports"
                              pause="400"
                              selected-object="selectedSport"
                              remote-url="/ajax/getSports"
                              remote-url-request-formatter="remoteUrlRequestFn"
                              remote-url-data-field="items"
                              title-field="name"                             
                              minlength="2"                        
                              input-class="form-control input-custom" />

            @*<input type="Search" placeholder="SEARCH" class="form-control input-custom" id="sports_input_box">*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
           {{sports.length}}
             <table class="table  table-bordered " id="sports-table">
                 <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>SPORTS NAME</td>
                        <td>SELECT SKILL LEVEL</td>

                        <td>ACTION</td>
                    </tr>               
                <tbody>                               
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in sports">
                        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td style="position: relative;top: 10px;">
                            <select class="example" name="" ng-change="updatePlayerSkill(item.id)" ng-bind="SportsModel.skill_level">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="icons-tab">
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="UpdateSport(item.id)"></i></a>
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="RemoveSport(item.id)"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="sports.length === 0"><td colspan="5">No Sports Added</td></tr>                
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is a possible solution for this since I am updating the array by pushing the elements and its not reflecting?

I am using Angular Js 1.6, any help would be really appreciated.

please check the image

[image]

Comment: are you sure `genericSuccess(data).sport` actually returns the value you want pushed into the array?  for that matter, what is up with this totally redundant function call in the first place?

Comment: yes ofcoure . I have checked by logging the object in console

Comment: then() takes a callback function with only one argument: the http response.

Comment: yes it does....

Comment: Than why are you passing a function with 4 arguments, and trying to access properties Success and Message which don't exist on a http response?

Comment: let me remove it then .... i kept the previous angular js version in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to surround the code that is pushing the element in the array with a $timeout **(Don't forget to inject the $timeout in your controller)**. This will trigger the diggest cycle and update the bindings, as can be seen [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

`

```
$http.post("/usersports/post_sport", $scope.sport).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {           
       $timeout(function(){ 
            $scope.sports.push(genericSuccess(data).sport);
            console.log($scope.sports);
       });
    });
```

`

Comment: Solved , thanks your answer works but I found the problem my Controller scope was not within the domain of that Table ... as you can see the Div on which the controller was it ended before the table div.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because from what I see in **angucomplete-alt** library, the **selected** parameter can be **null**. You need to handle that:

```
$scope.countrySelected = function(selected) {
  if (selected) {
    window.alert('You have selected ' + selected.title);
  } else {
    console.log('cleared');
  }
};
```

Regarding your primary question. Using asynchronus requests, it could happen that you go out of Angular **$digest** cycle. Try to wrap array.push with **$scope.applyAsync()** to refresh the view.